Use graphql-schema-linter with a CJS config file
I have a command to run the linter graphql-schema-linter -c build-util/config but we have upgraded our project to use Vite instead of Laravel Mix. We are now using CJS files for some of the JS files including the graphql-schema-linter.config.cjs instead of graphql-schema-linter.config.js. Is there a way for graphql-schema-linter to use this renamed config file? I have tried the following but still it doesn't read it.

graphql-schema-linter -c build-util/config/*.cjs
graphql-schema-linter -c build-util/config/graphql-schema-linter.config.cjs

If I do graphql-schema-linter -c ./build-util/config -p ./build-util/config/*.cjs, I can see that the config file is being read (I have added a console.log in graphql-schema-linter.config.cjs). But in the documentation, the -p is for custom rule path, not a config path.

I have found a way in case you are not allowed to rename files from .js to .mjs.
Example, in your package.json file, if you have a script that imports a configuration JS file and does not support any other files, then you can just switch from type commonjs, execute the script, then switch back to type module.
Example one of the package.json scripts
"lint:gql": "npm run lint-gql ./src/services/**/mywholeschema.graphql"`

Then before and after npm run, change the module type back and forth:
"lint:gql": "npm pkg set type=\"commonjs\" && npm run lint-gql ./src/services/**/mywholeschema.graphql && npm pkg set type=\"module\""`

As you can see, the npm run lint-gql ./src/services/**/mywholeschema.graphql is now sorrounded by scripts that will change the type in package.json.
